# How to keep player from moving off screen without using SKCameraNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game, I can't really use the CameraNode because it'll screw up the way everything looks and moves properly. My player is moving along the x axis and I have this set up in my update() func:

```
 if player.position.x > 50.0 {

     foregroundNode.position = CGPointMake(-(player.position.x - 50), 0)

    }
```

However, my player still moves off screen when tapped too much. How do I make it so that it will stay on the screen but the foreground node will still move backwards as my player moves forward? Will post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to do something like

```
if player.position.x < 50
{
   let dx = 50 - player.position.x  // if player is at 49, the change is 1
   player.position.x = 50
   background.position.x += dx // we want to add dx and not subtract because the background moves in the opposite direction of the player
}
```